# Virtualising map of a building's room for iPhone

Tags: iphone, dictionary

Recently I've seen a nice app which is virtualising map of a shopping plaza and users are able to use it for navigation purposes, I've tried to find the method or technology to do this but I couldn't find any thing (except some articles about OpenGL), May I know how can I implement something like this? for me navigation is not important. I just want to show rooms of a building. Thanks

Comment: can you pls share which app was that? Apple recently bought WiFiSLAM, an "indoor GPS" company, so it might change in the future but as far as I know inside a building it is not possible to track gps signals precisely and continuously. SO answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318437/how-to-obtain-the-current-location-inside-a-building-using-an-iphone

Comment: App name is Sunway Pyramid, it has been built for Sunway shopping mall in Kuala lumpur, I just need to show location of each room like building layout, currently adding navigation feature is not important.

Comment: When you say the location of each you room, you mean like a map? Surely if all your doing is displaying a map then you won't need the same technology used in the app you mentioned.

Comment: Yes like a map, but I need to update this layout every 15 mins as I have to show some information for each room , ok here is the story, imagine classes in a university, there are different modules running in different classes, I want to show module information on each class layout, then students will find their classes easily, there are 4 campuses and each building has 5 stories, in each level there are around 10-15 classrooms. using building layouts is an idea but doesn't look that nice. btw, I would like to know the technology that they are using and would like to experience it. Thank you.